# jQuery dynamic div slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-slider

For some reason I am having a lot of trouble finding this...

Basically looking for a jquery slider plugin (with next and previous button), where the content can be any thing (div's,text, images, a combination,etc). The problem comes that I the content will be dynamically added, for example, if I have something like

```
<ul>
    <li> /* some divs, images, etc*/ </li>
    <li> /* some divs, images, etc*/ </li>
    <li> /* some divs, images, etc*/ </li>
</ul>
```

then I can dynamically add "

" tags to the "" via javascript and this wont break the slider.

I am currently using [easy slider](http://cssglobe.com/easy-slider-17-numeric-navigation-jquery-slider/) but it dosent really support the contents of the slider being 'dynamic'

thanks in advance.

Comment: There are many alternative sliders, take a look at this http://www.basic-slider.com pretty simple

Comment: thanks. ANd I know there many and I have tried many. but this has the same problem as the other, that it screws up when you dynamically add an "<li>" tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

this is custom way of creating a slider for next previous

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
  slideRightShow: function(speed) {
    return this.each(function() {
        $(this).show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, +speed || 1000);
    });
  },
  slideLeftHide: function(speed) {
    return this.each(function() {
      $(this).hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, +speed || 1000);
    });
  },
  slideRightHide: function(speed) {
    return this.each(function() {
      $(this).hide('slide', {direction: 'right'}, +speed || 1000);
    });
  },
  slideLeftShow: function(speed) {
    return this.each(function() {
      $(this).show('slide', {direction: 'left'}, +speed || 1000);
    });
  }
});
```

[Try This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gq25M/1/)